# Android/Andengine/BaseGameUtils: When having multiple accounts on device "Choose an account" dialog shows every time you open the game

Tags: android, andengine, google-play-games

Android/BaseGamesUtil: When having multiple accounts on device "Choose an account" dialog shows every time the game starts. Is there a way to remember the account that the user selected when prompted first time and not ask him to choose an account every time he calls the game?

[image]

I've not messed or tried changing the basegameutils classes. I'm just calling the following three as required.

```
mHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();

mHelper.disconnect();

mHelper.signOut();
```

But whetner or not i signout/disconnect. The choose account popup reappears when i reopen the game. How to avoid showing this dialog once the user has selected the account he wants to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the issue. I was calling mHelper.disconnect(); everytime the user exited the application. This internally was signing the user out of the Games services. Hence the popup to select an account to sign in with every time the app started. I removed this call and it's all good now.

Only one thing I'm concerned about now. Will this cause any type of battery issues? If i don't sign out? Please let me know.

Comment: not signing out will not have any battery impact.  Signing in repeatedly probably does more activity...

Comment: agree. eventually noticed that.